# Need help with a cipher: "poems" with capital letters

Tags: cipher, real, unsolved-mysteries

I am trying to figure out a cipher I *think* I found in a book from 1982 and it's a 36 year old mystery we are trying to solve (I will reveal the book if this turns out to be something so everyone can play along!).  The book has several poems in it that has has lines that start with capital letters.  There is also several things that should be capitalized (like a name or place) that aren't capitalized and things that randomly made their own line in the puzzle.  I thought it was weird so I typed them out and there were double and triple letters.  I tried putting them in online puzzle solvers but nothing came up except gibberish.  I also thought maybe the spaces meant new words, but nothing!

There is another post that I saw (that's how I found this site) that was similar using a columnar transposition cipher but I'm not sure if it is the same!

Three of the twelve did not have any double letters and there are several others poems in the book that mean something.

> FCFTTNTNISSPISTWOFIDLTA
> AFIFOAFHWTGFTN
> ITNXTIAINWWFYFAAETLI
> BAIBFBOSFSPAFTSF
> LTYWTOWCABBOTWAFGT
> OMCSBSHHFOMEEOWBBBEWFW
> ATNHEJFSNRIIOTGGTT
> VMAAFAFAFSSCAAPTBWSTPYOOAT
> TWNWBAAYSSSELOY
> IOFEIYCANSITOHVTOFOLAIOTB
> PIDRTTDWWAIJAATUWOLATBDY
> WMBACRLBIFFTTIFCFSOBH

These are the "extra" poems:

> TNAESFSSFWBDFAEM
> WFFEFEGQBCCETHISTFFRDAIGTOLGAATRTPIATRASADBTNHAFCPCEGVEWTFF
> KTTT
> NWEGCTFFMTDSTFANATSSNH
> TTSIBMHAFFWTWOAAFETFF
> ASYFCTTWWFFFG

Comment: How sure are you that the first letters are the only important parts here?

Comment: Can you post the full poem as well? How can we be sure that this isn't just gibberish you pulled?

Comment: If this isn't real, forgive my edit

Comment: Yes, its real and not gibberish.  I will just tell you guys what the book is because I know I can't figure it out.  Hopefully someone can and find one of the treasures.  In 1982 a guy named Byron Preiss wrote a book called The Secret, a Treasure Hunt and hid 12 casques throughout 12 North American cities.  Since 19821, only 2 of the 12 have ever been found (Chicago in 1983 and Cleveland in 2004).  The poems are long (all of them put together), otherwise I would post them.  If you google the book you can find all the poems and what cities people think they are in.  Good luck!

Comment: @Rubio As far as I can tell no one has come up with this cipher.  I believe the only ones that are important are the first letters (besides using the clues in the verse to guide you too) as part of a secret cipher for several reasons.Preiss doesn't give us a way in the book to match up the picture and the verse, only tells us to match them up.There are a ton of combinations that they could be so there has to be a way for us to tell which is which.If you google the verses you will see that things like oz and wonderstone aren't capitalize, but they should be because they are places/people.

Comment: http://thesecret.pbworks.com/w/page/22148585/To%20Do